# Button like of FB does not work

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add the "like" button of FB, but it does not work.
I have follow FB instructions, read forum, I don't undestand what append.

The page is here : 
http://igive-preprod.herokuapp.com/

The share button works good.

And the code of my page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '<my_key>',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.1'
        });
      };

     (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=<my_key>&version=v2.1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://igive-preprod.herokuapp.com" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help.

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this link : 
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/profile/?uid=100001996284777

There is a problem only with Chrome because of a browser option.

I have unactivate this option (Go in Chrome -> Settings -> Privacy -> Content Settings -> Cookies and "Block third-party cookies and site data" must be unchecked) and now, it works good.

But I don't understand how this button can work on FB website.